# Do whirlpools of turbulence exist in stars just like the whirlpools that exist in water?

Tags: star-systems, plasma-physics, turbulence

Is there turbulence  in the hot plasma and gas of stars that is mathematically the same as whirlpools in water?

Comment: Yes there is turbulence.  No it's not mathematically the same because plasma is conductive and carries a magnetic field, the motions in the sun are not hydrodynamic, but magnetohydrodynamic -  Obligatory xkcd https://xkcd.com/1851/

Comment: This paper https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aaf797#:~:text=There%20is%20an%20abundance%20of,occupy%202.8%25%20of%20the%20photosphere. seems relevant